# control motor with raspberry pi and pi4j 2.0

Tags: dc-motor

I want to control a motor and a servo motor using a Raspberry Pi.
As I searched, all projects are for pi4j v1.0.
I'll be grateful if you guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There must be hundreds of tutorials not using pi4j.  You need to try searching again.

Comment: I did a very quick google search. "pi4j tutorial" gives many results. Likewise, "pi4j motor control" returns several results.

Comment: There are tutorials for controlling a motor with Pi4j 1.0,  but I could not find any tutorial for controlling a motor using Pi4j 2.0 ! @NomadMaker

Comment: is V2.0 that much different from V1.0? ... what kind of a motor are you trying to control? ... how is the motor connected to the RPi?

Comment: @jsotola
I have nothing to do with their difference.
I just want to use pi4j v2 to control a servo motor and a normal dc motor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the CrowPi example project, several examples are available for different types of motors, all using V2 of Pi4J.

More info about the project on:

- https://pi4j.com/getting-started/crowpi/

Code is available on:

- https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j-example-crowpi/blob/main/src/main/java/com/pi4j/crowpi/components/ServoMotorComponent.java
- https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j-example-crowpi/blob/main/src/main/java/com/pi4j/crowpi/components/StepMotorComponent.java
- https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j-example-crowpi/blob/main/src/main/java/com/pi4j/crowpi/components/VibrationMotorComponent.java