# PCA9685GpioExample for pi4j 2

Tags: i2c, servo, pi4j

I want to use [THIS](https://www.javatips.net/api/project-latex-master/3rdParty/pi4j-1.0-SNAPSHOT/examples/PCA9685GpioExample.java#) sample in my project.
But its library is for pi4j version 1 and I use the pi4j version 2.
I searched and I didn't find any sample for PCA9685 with pi4j2.
Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: You have two choices.  Learn to program (pretty much the point of the Pi) or hire someone to write a program for you.

Comment: I would suggest to do the following to convert your already working pj4j1 program to pj4j2. (1) Test the pj4j1 program to make sure it is working for your rpi. (2) Study the pj4j1 program to see which pj4j2 I2C, GPIO functions (actually not that many, :))are used. (2) Convert the above couple of i2c/gpio functions one by one (3) Test the complete program using pj4j2 functions/class/library.

Comment: @joan How can you write a program without required libraries??
I didn't say I don't know how to write code. I said I can't find the libraries.
I know enough programming and if you don't have a solution, it's better not to answer!

Comment: @tlfong01 Thank you. I would try your suggested ways.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/138446/servomotor-i2c-module

Comment: You appear to be asking us to write your code. Pi4J originally used WiringPi (which is now deprecated). V2 uses different GPIO libraries which are (inadequately) described on the website. You have 3 choices;  use V1, write your own code using V2 or a better supported language. If you study the PCA9685 data sheet it should not be that difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Adafruit has a very nice guide on this with some easy to follow instructions. You can find it at" [https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-servo-driver-with-raspberry-pi"](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-servo-driver-with-raspberry-pi%22) There are several tutorials on line to help you. I used "raspberry pi PCA9685" as the search term. This may not completely solve your problem but it is a good start.